# Application crashes when i try to debug

Tags: android, debugging

My application works fine when I run it, but when I want to debug to see a variable value the application crashes. The full debug log is below.
I don't know what is the error to correct it. Can you help me guys?
I read something about `Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8606', transport: 'socket'` and I disabled and enabled ADB Integration and didn't helped me. I tried to clean,rebuild and run the project again and didn't helped me. Every time I try to start debugging the application  crashes.

Thank you in advance!!

```
  Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8606', transport: 'socket'
    I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    I/System.out: debugger has settled (1421)
    W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.rares.echipahandbaltema2-2/lib/x86
    I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.rares.echipahandbaltema2, real application class is null.
    W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.rares.echipahandbaltema2-2/lib/x86
    W/art: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<com.example.rares.echipahandbaltema2.MainActivity$1>
    W/art: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<com.example.rares.echipahandbaltema2.MainActivity$1>
    I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
    W/art: Not able to initialize class for SetValues: java.lang.Class<com.example.rares.echipahandbaltema2.MainActivity$1>
    A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0xb04f6400, GetDebugThread()=0xb04f6400) Expected event thread
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingForDebuggerSend
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c841f0 self=0xb04f6400
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5810 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaba52920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=1 core=1 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xab956000-0xab958000 stackSize=1014KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00527f13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+67)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00527ce7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+615)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0039b74d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+733)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0043d6c0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL25DexFile_defineClassNativeEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP8_jstringP8_jobjectS7_S7_+448)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 001c5352  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (???)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native method)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:296)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:289)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:418)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] All threads:
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] DALVIK THREADS (12):
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 Runnable
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c841f0 self=0xb04f6400
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5810 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaba52920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=2 core=1 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xab956000-0xab958000 stackSize=1014KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0055befb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+1115)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 005521be  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+590)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00551d32  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+962)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00528168  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState14DumpAllThreadsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+424)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00527eb6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+1078)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 0039b74d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+733)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 0043d6c0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL25DexFile_defineClassNativeEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP8_jstringP8_jobjectS7_S7_+448)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 001c5352  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_DexFile_defineClassNative__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ldalvik_system_DexFile_2+222)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native method)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:296)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:289)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:418)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Suspended
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=2 dsCount=1 obj=0x74ff0610 self=0xac80b400
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5803 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb0bcc534
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=15 core=1 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xbf5fc000-0xbf5fe000 stackSize=8MB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc1/0x194
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x740
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x22
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0011d1de  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+142)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0011d147  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+39)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00558e8d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList22SuspendSelfForDebuggerEv+589)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 001bce3b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg11SuspendSelfEv+43)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0039a8bc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState15SuspendByPolicyENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+252)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0039ae13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+499)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0043d6c0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL25DexFile_defineClassNativeEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP8_jstringP8_jobjectS7_S7_+448)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 001c5352  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_DexFile_defineClassNative__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ldalvik_system_DexFile_2+222)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native method)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:296)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:289)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:418)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance!(Native method)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java:-1)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Native (still starting up)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xb04f5000
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5808 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xabc52920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=3 core=1 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xabb54000-0xabb56000 stackSize=1022KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc1/0x194
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x740
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x22
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0011d1de  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+142)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0011d147  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+39)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0055e202  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadPool7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+258)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0055d505  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+117)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0055ccda  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+106)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00075082  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c84160 self=0xa2ca7e00
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5809 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xabb51920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xaba55000-0xaba57000 stackSize=1014KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0xd7/0x19f
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0x6e/0x9c
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x22
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077ff1  /system/lib/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+33)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 000289df  /system/lib/libc.so (sigwait+95)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0052eaeb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9SignalSet4WaitEv+59)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0052e4b7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13WaitForSignalEPNS_6ThreadERNS_9SignalSetE+215)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0052c61a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+314)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00075082  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Binder:5803_1" prio=5 tid=5 Native
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c84550 self=0xa2caa600
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5815 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xab441920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xab345000-0xab347000 stackSize=1014KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0xb9a/0xd63
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0xe96/0x130c
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x36b/0x415
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x4a/0x6a
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x22
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077c2c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+28)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 000226d7  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+71)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00047797  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+279)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0004793a  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+42)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 000481ff  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+95)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0006ecde  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android10PoolThread10threadLoopEv+46)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00012095  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+309)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0007005b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00075082  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" prio=5 tid=6 Waiting
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c843a0 self=0xa2ca9c00
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5813 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xab749920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xab647000-0xab649000 stackSize=1038KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc1/0x194
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x740
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x22
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0011d1de  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+142)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0011d147  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+39)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 004371b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadExibNS_11ThreadStateE+537)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 004398a3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+339)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00451c2f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL11Object_waitEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+95)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 000006dc  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__+104)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - waiting on <0x0e62f27c> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:269)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - locked <0x0e62f27c> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:249)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Binder:5803_2" prio=5 tid=7 Native
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c845e0 self=0xac80c300
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=5816 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa598b920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xa588f000-0xa5891000 stackSize=1014KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0xb9a/0xd63

    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0001ef17  /system/lib/libc.so (accept4+55)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0001eed6  /system/lib/libc.so (accept+54)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00023808  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (???)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0029ab3c  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_libcore_io_Posix_accept__Ljava_io_FileDescriptor_2Ljava_net_SocketAddress_2+168)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native method)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:64)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.system.Os.accept(Os.java:43)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept(LocalSocketImpl.java:336)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.net.LocalServerSocket.accept(LocalServerSocket.java:90)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:150)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5810 (JDWP)

            [ 01-08 11:07:34.329  1197: 1197 W/         ]
            debuggerd: handling request: pid=5803 uid=10078 gid=10078 tid=5810
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8606', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be your fault.  The ART VM had a failure-  Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread().  See the duplicate for discussions of work arounds.  It appears that its a Google bug and will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: ProglsMetal is your issue fixed??

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is not clear, but I suspect it that it might be due to Instant run stored files.

So try disabling the instant run and disconnect the device, uninstall the app in the device and now try debugging it.

Hope it works.

To be more precise to turn off instant run in android studio:
1) Go to File-> Settings -> Search for instant run and uncheck it.

Comment: I've tried this and it works. But, do I have to do it each time I want to debug?

Comment: No need.. only for the first time try disabling it. Next time it should probably work normally

Comment: Ding Ding!!!  This is the answer!!

Comment: This did not work for me, however after trying above then removing all breakpoints (as recommended in another post) it worked.

Comment: This worked for me