# Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0x7f7f241e00, GetDebugThread()=0x7f7f241e00) Expected event thread

Tags: android-studio

Android Debugger Exception ;

```
    A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0x7f7f241e00, GetDebugThread()=0x7f7f241e00) Expected event thread
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingForDebuggerSend
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d1f700 self=0x7f7f241e00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application crashes when i try to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530788/application-crashes-when-i-try-to-debug)

Answer (score 2):

File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.